# Crystal report count insterd of sum

Tags: count, crystal-reports, sum

I am using Crystal report and I want to get the sum of group.
These are my columns with data type.

Customer - String

Item - String

Qty - Decimal

SalesPrice -Decimal

Value -Decimal

This is GroupBy Customer and I want to get the sum of Qty. But output is count of rows. 
How can I solve this issue..
[image]

Comment: is this a summary field shown below?

Comment: yes these fields are summery fields..

Answer (score 2):

sometimes Crystal report has this "bug" that causes sum to count

eventhough it is set to SUM it still counts the items

adding a **tonumber** solves this issue.

all you have to do is create a formula field for your column and use tonumber

[image]

you don't need to add it to the report but instead

add a summary operation using this formula field instead of your field.
(you can now select that formula field to sum - in my case "tonumave" is my tonumber formula)

by using tonumber before sum causes each data to be converted first to number which then enables sum to perform correctly.

[image]

this solves the problem if your summary field is counting instead of summarizing

Answer (score 1):

If this field was a summary (You right clicked on a certain field, then you chose to insert --> Summary) Then you can right click on it, then choose `Edit Summary`, then instead of `Count` choose `Sum`.

Comment: Yes. Already I have done like you mention above. But result is count. not sum.

Comment: What field are you summarizing?

Comment: Qty, SalesPrice and Value

Comment: Please send us a screen shot about the format of this sumary, and the desing of your report